# I want to get group_id from the url , I am using angular 5, I am not able to get group_id , I have shared sample link and code

Tags: html, css, node.js, angular, typescript

```
const ssoToken = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['token'];
const urlId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

if (ssoToken) {
  value = ssoToken;
  console.log(value,"this is value")
  
} else if(urlId){
  value = urlId;
}else {
  value = window.location.origin;
}
if (value != urlId) {
  try {
    if (ssoToken) {
      this.resAuth = jwt_decode(value);
    } else {
      this.resAuth = value;
    }
```

I have tried with this.route.snapshot.queryParams but didn't get it,And here is the link=>
localhost:4200/login?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjb21tdW5pdHlfaWQiOiJmMTMyOWM5MC01ZTg1LTExZWMtOTg1Ny02OWMxNjdlYjIwOTIiLCJiYXRjaF9pZCI6ImVjZDdhODAwLTk5ZmItMTFlYy1iZWM1LTM3ODNjYmJjYThkOCJ9.7jtm5xaMXUYrAuB5v0H6ipso5olzyPsnu-OwluXm0k8group_id=0rpe0

Comment: Did you want to get the grou_id from the token?

Comment: @Shafkhan yes I am trying to get group_id from url

Comment: please show your routing configurations as well. I would recommend adding this to a stackblitz app and update the link here so I or anyone can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Update Your Link and Put(&) after token ...&group_id=0rpe0

and get

```
const urlId = this.route.snapshot.params['group_id'];
```